# HSQLDB bundle in felix org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver not found

Tags: osgi, bundle, hsqldb, apache-felix

I have some code, what loaded:
1) HSQLDB v. 2.2.8 bundle
2) Bundle with service:

```
   package ihtika2.i_internalfunctions.service;

import com.google.code.ihtika.Vars.Ini;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

/**
 *
 * @author Arthur
 */
public class InternalFunctions implements InternalFunctionsInterface {

    // launch browser
    public void launchBrowser(String uriStr) {
        Desktop desktop;
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
                // launch browser
                URI uri;
                try {
                    uri = new URI("http://" + uriStr);
                    desktop.browse(uri);
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                } catch (URISyntaxException use) {
                    use.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void initDB() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
            Ini.conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:Db/pages");
            Ini.stmt = Ini.conn.createStatement();
            Ini.rs = null;

            Ini.rs = Ini.stmt.executeQuery("select count(1) as qwe from "
                    + " information_schema.system_tables "
                    + "where table_schem = 'PUBLIC'"
                    + "and table_name = 'PAGES';");
            Ini.rs.next();
            if (Ini.rs.getInt("qwe") == 0) {
                Ini.stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE SEQUENCE SEQU");
                Ini.stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE CACHED TABLE PAGES (id bigint "
                        + "GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS SEQUENCE SEQU PRIMARY KEY, "
                        + "url varchar(7777), lastUpdateDate varchar(7777)) ");
                Ini.stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE CACHED TABLE LINKDATA (id int, "
                        + "nazvanie varchar(777), linkURL varchar(777), razmer varchar(777)) ");
                Ini.stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE INDEX linkDataID ON LINKDATA (id)");
                Ini.stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE INDEX pagesURL ON PAGES (url)");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Ini.logger.fatal("Error on DB init", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

3) Some bundle, what calls bundle number 2.

```
 try {
        ServiceReference[] refs = context.getServiceReferences(
                InternalFunctionsInterface.class.getName(), "(Funct=IFuncts)");
        if (refs == null) {
            System.out.println("Not Found IFuncts on init");
        } else {
            InternalFunctions = (InternalFunctionsInterface) context.getService(refs[0]);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Ini.logger.fatal("Error on IFuncts init", ex);
    }

    InternalFunctions.initDB();
```

On executing I get error in logs:

```
 [FATAL] 2012-08-02 20:18 root (InternalFunctions.java:initDB:61)
Error on DB init
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver not found by ihtika2.I_InternalFunctions [7]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1460)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:72)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at ihtika2.i_internalfunctions.service.InternalFunctions.initDB(InternalFunctions.java:40)
    at ihtika2.mainform.IC_MainForm.<init>(IC_MainForm.java:66)
    at ihtika2.mainform.IC_MainForm$4.run(IC_MainForm.java:225)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:701)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:671)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Please, advice - how to use HSQLDB bundle in other bundle?

**Answered by me:
 The solution is using**

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new JDBCDriver());
Ini.conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:Db/pages");
```

insted of using

```
Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
Ini.conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:Db/pages");
```

Comment: If you find a solution to your own question, post it as an answer rather than editing your own question. Then you can accept that answer, so that others can see it is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a very OSGi unfriendly solution. You might want to take a look at H2. H2 implements the OSGi spec, it provides a org.osgi.service.jdbc.DataSourceFactory service. You might also want to raise a bug at the hsqldb project and ask for OSGi support, it is trivially to implement for them.